# Reintegrate ARMA model

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have a model with multiple seasonalities, where, even fitting fourier terms,seasonal correlation don´t dissappear. Looking at my ACF, I need to make non-seasonal differencing and seasonal differencing for each of the three seasonalities. If I manualy differenciate the series I can reconstruct it with

`integrate = cumsum(rbind(firstdiff,as.matrix(na.omit(wn.ts))))`

> Where "firstdiff" is the first value of the original series and "wn.ts" is the differenced series(one difference)

My question is, why is it that, when i try tu use the same logic with the Arima fitted values

`integrate = cumsum(rbind(firstdiff,as.matrix(na.omit(arimaM$fitted))))`

> Where arimaM is a model fitted over the differenced series "wn.ts"

The result is not the original series?

Here is the code of this example to keep it simple (only one difference)

```
noise <- rnorm(26295)
x[1] <- noise[1]
x[2] <- noise[2]
theta = .85
theta2 = -.63
wn = NULL

for (i in 3:26295) {
x[i] = .00000082*i+x[i-1]+theta*noise[i-1]+theta2*noise[i-2]+noise[i] 
}

rw <- ts(x, start=2015, f=8765)
plot(rw)

firstdiff = head(rw)[1]

for(i in 2:26295) {   #Differencing
wn[i] <- x[i-1]-x[i]
}

wn.ts = ts(wn, start=2015, f=8765)

plot(wn.ts, type ='l')

integrate = cumsum(rbind(firstdiff,as.matrix(na.omit(wn.ts)))) #Integrate original series
plot(integrate, type='l' )
points(x, col = 'red', type='l') #Check integration/inverse differentiation is done correctly

arimaM = Arima(rw, c(0,1,2)) #Arima over original series

arima2 = Arima(wn, c(0,0,2), include.mean = F) #Arima over differentiated series

model = Arima(rw, model = arima2)

integrate2 = cumsum(rbind(firstdiff,as.matrix(na.omit(arima2$fitted)))) #Integrate fitted series
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(ts(integrate2, s=2015,f=8765), type='l', main= 'Reintegrated ARMA(0,0,2)' )
plot(arimaM$fitted, main='ARIMA (0,1,2)')
plot(model$fitted, main = 'model = Arima(rw, model = arima2)' )
```

[image]

Comment: Are the model parameters the same in ARIMA(0,1,2) and reintegrated ARIMA(0,0,2)?

Comment: Yes, the only parameters of both models are the order (p,d,q), I edited the question to add my code, is a random walk simulation and then a white noise.

Comment: I meant coefficient values, not the lag orders. Are the estimated autoregressive and moving-average coefficients the same?

Comment: Ohhhh, I see, AR and MA are the same, but the second model include a mean term. Now that I removed it the integration is done correctly. Thanks!!

Comment: Forget it, reintegrated model looks like the inverse of the original data. I also tried fitting the differentiated model to the original data but the result is the same (third graph). Only the second graph is correct (ARIMA). Coefficients are the same

Comment: The current version of the post is a little hard to understand. I am missing the actual question.

Comment: I would like to know why is it that fitting an ARMA model on a differentiated data and then doing integration don´t result on an approximation of the observed data. When I use the cumsum function on the observed differentiated data and the observed first value of non-differentiated data, I obtain the original data, but doing the same with the fitted values(of ARMA model), instead of the original values it results on a graph that looks like the inverse of the original data. In the plot, the first graph correspond to this step, the second is how it should look like.